# find string inside a gzipped file in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, directory, grep, gzip

My current problem is that I have around 10 folders, which contain gzipped files (around on an average 5 each). This makes it 50 files to open and look at.

Is there a simpler method to find out if a gzipped file inside a folder has a particular pattern or not?

```
zcat ABC/myzippedfile1.txt.gz | grep "pattern match"
zcat ABC/myzippedfile2.txt.gz | grep "pattern match"
```

Instead of writing a script, can I do the same in a single line, for all the folders and sub folders?

```
for f in `ls *.gz`; do echo $f; zcat $f | grep <pattern>; done;
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

zgrep will look in gzipped files, has a -R recursive option, and a -H show me the filename option:

```
zgrep -R --include=*.gz -H "pattern match" .
```

OS specific commands as not all arguments work across the board:

**Mac 10.5+:** `zgrep -R --include=\*.gz -H "pattern match" .`

**Ubuntu 16+:** `zgrep -i -H "pattern match" *.gz`

Comment: FWIW, my zgrep doesn't support -R

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, Thanks for giving a direction. But for me following worked zgrep options "pattern" files

Comment: `zgrep -R --include=\*.gz -H "pattern"` on zsh

Comment: `zgrep (gzip) 1.4` -- latest on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS doesn't have `-R` not include.

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: "-R: option not supported"

Comment: On a Mac terminal, include also doesn't seem to be supported `/sw/bin/zgrep: --include=*.gz: option not supported`

Answer (score 21):

You don't need *zcat* here because there is *zgrep* and *zegrep.*

If you want to run a command over a directory hierarchy, you use *find:*

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep ⟨pattern⟩ \{\} \;
```

And also “`ls *.gz`” is useless in *for* and you should just use “*.gz” in the future.

Comment: I get the lines which contain this pattern, but not the name of the file by this method. Is there some way to get that also listed?

Comment: `find . -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 zgrep pattern`?

Comment: Old grep trick: find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep ⟨pattern⟩ /dev/null \{\} \;    # That will make grep think that there is more than a single file and print the filename.

Comment: this doesnt tell me which file it found the pattern in

Answer (score 11):

how zgrep don't support -R

I think the solution of "Nietzche-jou" could be a better answer, but I would add the option -H to show the file name something like this

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H 'PATTERN' \{\} \;
```

Comment: yeah, this is the command that actually showed the file names too

Answer (score 8):

use the find command

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zcat "{}" + |grep "test"
```

or try using the recursive option (-r) of zcat

Comment: -bash-3.00$ find . -name "*.gz" -exec zcat "{}" + | grep "NOT OK"
find: missing argument to `-exec'

something seems to be missing after exec?

Comment: maybe try changing to find ... +; | grep ... and see

Comment: You must terminate the "-exec" option with ";"

Comment: "find -exec cmd {} +" is relatively new, so if you have an older find it may not support "+".  It is similar to "find -print0 | xargs -0 cmd".

Comment: It works. :) Just wanted to know how do we get the file name having matched string. Above command gives the line only with match string.

Answer (score 7):

Coming in a bit late on this, had a similar problem and was able to resolve using;

```
zcat -r /some/dir/here | grep "blah"
```

As detailed here;

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man1/gzip.1.html

However, this does not show the original file that the result matched from, instead showing "(standard input)" as it's coming in from a pipe. zcat does not seem to support outputting a name either.

In terms of performance, this is what we got;

```
$ alias dropcache="sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"

$ find 09/01 | wc -l
4208

$ du -chs 09/01
24M

$ dropcache; time zcat -r 09/01 > /dev/null
real    0m3.561s

$ dropcache; time find 09/01 -iname '*.txt.gz' -exec zcat '{}' \; > /dev/null
0m38.041s
```

As you can see, using the `find|zcat` method is significantly slower than using `zcat -r` when dealing with even a small volume of files. I was also unable to make zcat output the file name (using `-v` will apparently output the filename, but not on every single line). It would appear that there isn't currently a tool that will provide both speed and name consistency with grep (i.e. the `-H` option).

If you need to identify the name of the file that the result belongs to, then you'll need to either write your own tool (could be done in 50 lines of Python code) or use the slower method. If you do not need to identify the name, then use `zcat -r`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

`find  . -name "*.gz"|xargs zcat | grep "pattern"` should do.

Answer (score 2):

`zgrep "string" ./*/*`

You can use above command to search for `string` in .gz files of `dir` directory where `dir` has following sub-directories structure:

```
/dir
    /childDir1
              /file1.gz
              /file2.gz
    /childDir2
              /file3.gz
              /file4.gz
    /childDir3
              /file5.gz
              /file6.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command -

```
zgrep "foo" $(find . -name "*.gz")
```