# Listing the contents of .tgz within a .tgz

Tags: shell, tar

I have 300 directories with the following structure

```
Directory
|-- zipfile.tgz
|    |-- anotherzip.tgz
|    |    |-- afurtherzip.tgz
|    |    |    |-- ethernet1.txt    
|    |    |    |-- ethernet2.txt    
|    |    |    |-- ethernet3.txt    
|    |    |-- files.txt
|    |-- files.txt
|-- zipfile2.tgz
|    |-- anotherzip.tgz
|    |    |-- afurtherzip.tgz
|    |    |    |-- ethernet1.txt    
|    |    |    |-- ethernet2.txt    
|    |    |    |-- ethernet3.txt    
|    |    |-- files.txt
|    |-- files.txt
```

I need to grep the contents of the ethernetx.txt files and for any files containing 'abc=n' have it tell me the file path of the containing zipfile.tgz so i know where to find it.

Can anyone suggest a decent script / one liner i can use to achieve this? I dont want to have to recursively extrace every .tgz if i can avoid it but please let me know what you think.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407111/performing-grep-operation-in-tar-files-without-extracting and you'll get to your desired output

Comment: Another solution using `zgrep` is listed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253816/find-string-inside-a-gzipped-file-in-a-folder

Comment: Thanks incognito, but that only deals with 1 level of depth in the tar, the file i want to grep is 3 levels deep (tar within a tar within a tar) How can this be adapted?