# Fastest way to grep through thousands of gz files?

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, find

I have thousands of .gz files all in one directory.  I need to grep through them for the string `Mouse::Handler`, is the following the fastest (and most accurate) way to do this?

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H 'Mouse::Handler' {} \;
```

Ideally I would also like to print out the line that I find this string on.

I'm running on a RHEL linux box.

Comment: Duplicate - use zgrep: [find-string-inside-a-gzipped-file-in-a-folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253816/find-string-inside-a-gzipped-file-in-a-folder)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can search in parallel using

```
find . -name "*.gz" | xargs -n 1 -P NUM  zgrep -H 'Mouse::Handler'
```

where `NUM` is around the number of cores you have.

Comment: When I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo` I get the following (condensed version).  Does this mean I have two processors each with 1 core?  If so, can I still use this trick with NUM=2? processor : 0
model name :       Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2651 v2 @ 1.80GHz
cpu cores : 1

processor : 1
model name :       Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2651 v2 @ 1.80GHz
cpu cores : 1

Comment: @Nosrettap So I would experiment with `NUM = 2` to start.

Comment: Will it have a big impact if I use too large of NUM?  Perhaps thrashing or something?

Comment: @Nosrettap Maybe. Experiment and see!

Comment: For extreme modes I'd recommend maximum to be N cores + 1. I find that adding more than that is not helpful. Setting job count equal to number of cores is even good enough. Why make your system suffer.