# Recursive grep for gz files search string from an output string

Tags: linux, bash, grep, cat

I'm trying to search a string from an output of a string in recursive search with gz files folder.

I'm using the command which is only worked:

```
find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H 'PATTERN' \{\} \;
```

from [find string inside a gzipped file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253816/find-string-inside-a-gzipped-file-in-a-folder)

How can I make this happen just like using normal grep with pipe as follow?

```
cat <folder> | grep 'pattern1' | grep 'pattern2'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your initial command looks at multiple files in a (tar.gz?) compressed file, searching for a single pattern, but your pseudo-code looks in a single file for multiple patterns. Which is it?

Comment: You should remove the `\ ` from `\{\}` if you expect this to be the file name. If you want to execute a pipe of several `grep` commands you can put this into a script like `zgrep -H 'pattern1' "$@" | grep 'pattern2'` and use `-exec script {} \;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pipe the find results through a second grep:

`find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H "PATTERN1" {} \; | grep "PATTERN2"`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your specific question

```
How can I make this happen just like using normal grep with pipe: cat | grep 'pattern1' | grep 'pattern2'
```

You can use `find` to `cat` all the files and then `grep`, but this won't be good because you will only get result lines without the filename.

It's better to just use two grep commands:

```
zgrep 'pattern1' *.gz | grep 'pattern2'
```

If you want to include subdirectories you can use the globstar (assuming you are running `bash`):

```
shopt -s globstar
zgrep 'pattern1' **.gz | grep 'pattern2'
```

Answer (score 0):

By your "pseudo-code" (cat | grep 'pattern2' | grep 'pattern3') do you mean?

If we have a file file.txt that contains:

```
pattern this text on the line <br>
pattern2 this text on the line <br>
this pattern3 <br>
pattern2pattern3 this line
```

then your "pseudo-code"

```
cat file.txt | grep 'pattern2' | grep 'pattern3'
```

would result in: `pattern2pattern3 this line`. If this is what you want, we could use

```
zcat file.gz | grep 'pattern1' | grep 'pattern2'
```

**But** if we look at the `find . -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -H 'PATTERN' \{\} \;` it is not even close to the samt thing because that would be more like:

```
   cat /**.*txt | grep 'pattern'
```

which it self is a bit special the samt result would be given by

```
grep -R 'pattern'
```

Then i would say it in the case of .gz (not sure if the /**/*.gz will work with zcat)

```
zcat /**/*.gz | grep 'pattern'
```